# Error in iterating an array of coordinates: "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable" (python)

Tags: python, compiler-errors

My program is supposed to compute the distance of the closest pair. It accepts two sorted arrays: xpts is an array of pairs/coordinates sorted by the x coordinate. ypts is an array sorted by the y coordinate. I am trying to use a divide and conquer technique, so I pass in half of the array recursively. However, I get an error.

> ```
> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable:  a1, pair1= closest_pair(xlft,ylft)
> ```

My code is:

```
def closest_pair(xpts,ypts):
  if xpts size < = 3: 
   if xsize==1:
        return xpts[0][0]
    elif xsize==2:
        return dist(xpts[0],xpts[1])
    else:
        one= xpts[0]
        two= xpts[1]
        three= xpts[2]
        s1= dist(one,two)
        s2= dist(two,three)
        s3= dist(one,three)
        s= (min(s1,s2,s3),min(xpts[0],xpts[1],xpts[2]))
    return s
  else:
   ...
    xlft= xpts[:xsize/2]
    xrht= xpts[(xsize/2)+1:]
    ylft= []
    yrht= []
    median= xpts[(xsize/2)-1][0]


    for p in ypts:
        if p[0] <= median:
            ylft.append(p)
        else:
            yrht.append(p)

    a1, pair1= closest_pair(xlft,ylft)
    a2, pair2= closest_pair(xrht,yrht)
    st= []
    if a1 < a2:
        a3, pair3= (a1,pair1)

    else:
        a3, pair3= (a2,pair2)

        for p in ypts:
            if  abs(p[0]-median) < a3:
                st.append(p)

                n_st= len(st)
                closest= (a3,pair3)
                if n_st>1:
                    for i in range(n_st-1):
                        for j in range(i+1,min(i+8,n_st)):
                            if dist(st[i],st[j]) < closest[0]:
                                closest= (dist(st[i],st[j]),(st[i],st[j]))
        d= closest
        return d


d1 = closest_pair(xpts, ypts)[0]
print d1
```

Comment: `if xpts size < = 3: bruteforce distance`. What is this line doing? How are there spaces between the names?

Comment: that is pseudocode for if the size of the x array is less/equal to 3, I manually compute the distance and return it.

Comment: Could you paste the code you've been using in place of the pseudocode? Because that is the code which returns something for the base case and that is causing the errors.

Comment: @Marek, it's the sequence unpacking `a1, pair1= closest_pair(xlft,ylft)` when `closest_pair` returns a float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if xsize==1:
        return xpts[0][0]
```

You are returning a float here. This is what's causing the errors.

Presumably, you have a list of coordinate tuples and indexing into the list and then the tuple gives you a `float` which cannot be iterated over. Hence, the message.

Answer (score 0):

`closest_pair` is returning a float, so

```
a1, pair1= closest_pair(xlft,ylft)
```

will cause the exception. This is called sequence unpacking and tries to iterate over the value of `closest_pair(xlft,ylft)`

The traceback includes the *line number* of the exception. It would be most helpful if you could include a marker (eg `#<== exception here`) corresponding to the line that is throwing the exception